# ggplot2 bar chart with 2 Y variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a simple bar chart with ggplot2 (in R). 
I would like to have 2 bars for each category.

```
 X   Y1     Y2
 A  0.53    0.01
 B  0.23    0.01
 C  0.15    0.05
 D  0.09    0.26
 E  0.01    0.67
```

So for A, I would like to have 2 bars equivalent to 0,53 (Y1) and 0,01 (Y2). For B, it would be 2 bars equivalent to 0,23(Y1) and 0,01(Y2) and so on.

This is what I tried so far:

```
   ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out how to get 2 Y variables. I am only able to put 1 Y variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape)    
dataframe <- melt(dataframe )
    dataframe  <- dataframe [complete.cases(dataframe ),]

    ggplot(data = dataframe , aes(x=X, y = value, fill = variable) ) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

If you want, you can also stack them by removing the position dodge statement.
You can change labels and axis title by using the normal ggplot command.